# LDIF idempotent apply tool

Tags: ldap, ldif

Before I write one, are there any tools for idempotent applying LDIFs:

1. If change type is not specified, add or replace an entry (aka `UPSERT`) (removing any attributes not mentioned in the LDIF record).
2. If change type is specified process like normal `ldapmodify`.

I saw someone suggesting `ldapmodify -c`, but this is meh :) I want to catch all errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing a new tool. Something like this https://github.com/ip1981/ldapply